# Sum in a controller issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm getting an error when i'm trying to do a condition and sum my other column

```
@dolars =Policy.find(:all ,:conditions=>"type_money = '1' ").sum(&:amount_ensure)
```

My table

```
Policies 
    |id|  |type_money| |amount_ensure|
   integer   integer     integer
```

My log is showing this

```
nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:52:in `+'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb:61:in `sum'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:211:in `inject'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb:61:in `each'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb:61:in `inject'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb:61:in `sum'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb:59:in `sum'
```

i'm trying to do this:

```
SELECT id, SUM(amount_ensure) As dolars,type_money
FROM Policies
WHERE type_money= "1"
```

The code in my controller should work but i don't know what happened

Someone can help me ? i will really appreciate all help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
 @dolars = Policy.sum(:amount_ensure ,:conditions=>"type_money = '1' ")
```

The above query performs the summation in sql itself

When you call `sum` after `find` it sums the records fetched from the query.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `nil` value for `#amount_ensure` somewhere.

Maybe this will make it more clear, in `irb`:

```
2.0.0p195 :001 > [1,2,3,4,nil].reduce(&:+)
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
    from (irb):1:in `+'
    from (irb):1:in `each'
    from (irb):1:in `reduce'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Well i used this in my last example and worked with the same sintaxis but i don't know what happen here

Comment: This worked for me @dolars=  Policy.find(:all ,:conditions=>"mount_type = '0'").sum(&:mount).

But is not working my conditions that i posted

Answer (score 1):

Try using the inject method, you could also cast .to_f so that nils are zeroed out.

```
@dolars =Policy.where(:type_money => 1).inject(0) { |sum, policy| sum += policy.amount_ensure.to_f }
```